# Dialogue Manager Godot 4 Signals

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot-4, plugin

When using the Dialogue Manager addon on Godot, I am trying to run a function to change the sprite of a character. My function look like this under my character script:

```
func ace_change_sprite(index):
    print("EEE")
    change_sprite(index)
```

and my dialogue looks like this:

```
~ start
: test
Ace: Hey Miyu!
do emit("AceUpdateSprite",3)
```

When I run this, it prints the "EEE" but it doesn't update the Sprite. My character script is AutoLoaded and I have tried using signals, but still got the same result of "EEE" being printed but nothing else happening.

My `change_sprite` function is this:

```
func change_sprite(index):
    $Sprite.texture = load(sprites_path + character_name + str(index) + ".png")
```

It works when I call it within the player script, changing the sprite, but when I call it outside it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This is wild speculation, but: are you sure there is only one character in the scene? I'm thinking there could be two (one autloaded, and one in the scene proper) and only one of them is getting the signal, and it is not the one you are looking at.

Comment: @Theraot I have only added once Character scene to it. Node Structure:
Node
-Characters (Node2D)
- - Ace (Node2D)

Ace is the character. Should I add the character through GDScript?

Comment: I would assume that the problem is that the `change_sprite` method either doesn't work or doesn't work the way you think it does. But [I can't find a method with that name anywhere in the official Godot reference](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/search.html?q=change_sprite), so I assume it's a function that you either wrote yourself or that is provided by the dialogue manager addon. If it's your own function, please post the sourcecode. If it's a 3rd party function, please link to the documentation.

Comment: @Philipp I have updated the question with the needed information. Also I know my function works since when I call it inside the character script, it changes the sprite.

Comment: My next step to troubleshoot this would be to add a statement `print(sprites_path + character_name + str(index) + ".png")` to the function to confirm that all these values are the values I expect them to be.

Comment: I have done that. It does work. I have 100% confirmed that the change_sprite() function works. It works unless I send a signal using Dialogue Manager. When I use a signal in the character code, it works, but not in Dialogue Manager.

Comment: @TheJalfireKnight So you confirmed that the `change_sprite` functions gets executed in both cases and you 100% confirmed that the argument is the same in both cases? And yet the texture gets changed in one case but not in the other?

Comment: could you try to preload the texture and saving it in an array? So it does not get loaded in the signal itself?

Comment: I did something similar to that, even though I would prefer a signal, it works. Thanks for the help @Bugfi5h